# fdisk partitions don't show with lsblk

Tags: linux, fdisk, lsblk

I've partitioned an external drive with `fdisk` and this are the results:

[image]

But when I run `lsblk` the partitions I created are not showing. What's the fault here?

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `w` command. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in `fdisk` remain in the memory of `fdisk` itself until you tell the tool to write them to the device. You do this with `w`. If you quit with `q`, the changes will be lost.

After writing the changes `fdisk` notifies the OS. In modern "big" distros this should be enough. From now on `lsblk` should show the new state of partitions.

I guess some old or limited versions of `fdisk` may not notify the OS. In this case invoke `partprobe /dev/sdb` (or just `partprobe`).

If `partprobe` is unavailable and the disk is external (e.g. connected via USB), `sync` just in case, disconnect and connect again. This should make the OS probe for partitions. If you cannot `partprobe` and you cannot disconnect the disk (e.g. the disk is internal, fixed), a reboot is the ultimate solution. Less drastic methods may or may not be available.